# How can I overcome "Unable to allocate 11.7 GiB for an array with shape (4128, 380433) and data type float64" when I merge two datasets?

Tags: pandas, merge

```
outcome_variables = pd.merge(ivs, v_dem, how="outer", on=["alpha-2", "year"])
```

Alpha-2 and year are the same type data however, still I get the error that is "Unable to allocate 11.7 GiB for an array with shape (4128, 380433) and data type float64". Is it important to have the same shape for the datasets? Or can be caused due to the fact the datasets have different kind of data types ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the issue is something *other* than running out of memory? Why would you assume the shape to be an issue?

Comment: If it is the memory problem, how can I deal with this? Any idea? Interestingly sometimes it gives memory error and when I try again it works.